# How do I return nested models as JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_images
  belongs_to :user
end
class SubImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image
end
```

Routes

```
/users/:user_id
/users/:user_id/images/:image_id
/users/:user_id/images/:image_id/subimages/:subimage_id

resources :users do
  resources :images, :controller => "Images" do
    resources :subimages, :controller => "SubImages" do
    end
  end
end
```

Goal: When I make the request to user 1 it should return all of the user 1 images and sub images nested.

Right now, the code only returns the user 1 images. I want it return sub images too.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ActiveModel Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) by Rails API. You need to create Serializer classes for your models and specifying the attributes that you require in your JSON output.

You can generate serializer for your existing models:

```
rails g serializer post
```

Given a Post and Comment model:

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :title, :body

  has_many :comments

  url :post
end
```

and

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :body

  belongs_to :post_id

  url [:post, :comment]
end
```

By default, when you serialize a Post, you will get its Comments as well.

Now, in your controllers, when you use render :json, Rails will now first search for a serializer for the object and use it if available.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    render json: @post
  end
end
```

In this case, Rails will look for a serializer named PostSerializer, and if it exists, use it to serialize the Post.

Comment: What if I want to use the serializer conditionally? not by default.

Comment: @erielmarimon add the condition in the calling controller.